# Squeryl: from not found

Tags: import, squeryl

Which import is needed for Squeryl's

```
from
```

statement?

Erroneous statement:

```
def users = from(MySchema.users)(u => where(u.id === user.id.id) select(u))
```

Error message: "not found: value from"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import

```
import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
```

was needed. Now it compiles.

Seems I am the only one who uses Squeryl...
Thanks for watching.

Comment: Far from it, but when you post 2 days before Christmas responses are bound to be a little slow....